# All values are placed on the x-axis when data is a subset of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, bar-chart, categorical-data

I am new to pandas and plotting data with python. I am trying to plot a subset of a pandas data frame with seaborn, and I get confusing results.

My data frame is a two column data frame with 50 values each - 50 randomly generated numbers representing names and 50 randomly generated floats representing values.
The 'names' column is categorical

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['names'] = np.arange(50)
df['values'] = np.random.uniform(low=-5.0, high=5.0, size=50)
df.names = df.names.astype('category')

# display(df.head())
  names    values
0     0 -4.455709
1     1 -1.020304
2     2  4.821457
3     3 -0.967358
4     4 -1.538404
```

When I plot the complete data set with plot using 'names' as the x-axis and 'values' as the y-axis

```
df.plot(kind='bar', x = 'names', y = 'values')
sns.barplot(data = df, x = 'names', y = 'values')
```

I get two identical bar charts with 50 bars (see links below)

[image: Full set bar chart with plot]

[image: Full set bar chart with seaborn]

When I plot a subset of 10 rows like this, on the other hand

```py
df[:10].plot(kind='bar', x = 'names', y = 'values')
sns.barplot(data = df[:10], x='names', y = 'values')
```

I get two different plots - plot gives a bar chart with 10 bars, while seaborn gives a bar chart with all 50 bars where only the 10 first have a value (see links below).

[image: subset bar chart with plot]

[image: subset bar chart with seaborn]

**How do I make the seaborn bar chart for the subset look like the plot bar chart for the subset?**

Comment: Because `df.names = df.names.astype('category')`. Seaborn will plot all the values from the category, because that's how the API works. If you look at `df.names`, you will see `dtype: category` and `Categories (50, int64): [0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 46, 47, 48, 49]`. Don't unnecessarily set a column as categorical.

Comment: The alternative is to set xlim. Regardless of the tick label names, the tick locations are 0 indexed. Assign the plot to a value: `ax = sns.barplot(...)`, and then set xlim: `_ = ax.set(xlim=(-0.5, 9.5))`